# report error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, plsql-package

I got this error report error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
on Oracle Apex v 20.2
When trying to parse data from .xlsx file to a report window when I increased the number of columns more than 85 columns , and my excel file got more than 300 columns still !

here is my query:

```
select line_number, col001, col002, col003, col004, col005, 
               col006, col007, col008, col009, col010,
                    col011,col012,col013,col014,col015,col016,col017,col018,col019,col020,col021,col022,col023,col024,col025,col026,col027,col028,col029,
                col030,col031,col032,col033,col034,col035,col036,col037,col038,col039,col040,col041,col042,col043,col044,col045,col046,col047,col048,col049,col050,col051  
                ,col052,col053,col054,col055,col056,col057,col058,col059,col060,col061,col062,col063,col064,col065,col066,col067,col068,col069,col070,
               col071,col072,col073,col074,col075,col076
               ,col078,col079,col080,col081,col082,col083,col084
               col085,col086,col087,col088,col089,col090 
                -- more columns (col011 to col300) can be selected here.


from apex_application_temp_files f, 
   table( apex_data_parser.parse(
              p_content                     => f.blob_content,
              p_add_headers_row             => 'Y',
              --
              p_xlsx_sheet_name             => :PX_XLSX_WORKSHEET,
              --
              p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
              p_file_name                   => f.filename ) ) p


where f.name = :PX_FILE
```

But If I select only 85 columns or less it works fine.

Any help !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't do it as you hit the limits.

However, what you might do is one of the following options:

- **split the file** into smaller *chunks* - 4 files with approx. 80 columns (as you said that 85 columns can be used). Each of them should contain the `ID` column which uniquely identifies each row, so that you could later "merge" them. That process probably requires 4 different database tables, as well as a little bit of programming efforts afterwards
- save the file as a CSV (textual) file. Use **SQL Loader** to load it into the database. It doesn't have such a restriction and is VERY FAST so - you'd load it all in a single run.

  - alternatively, you could use that file as a source for the **external table**. Note that this option requires access to the database server (while SQL Loader works with files on your own PC)